# Cannot change case of an application name

Tags: applications, macos, case

I have an application called LICEcap. It's a pretty handy app that allows you to take a GIF video of your screen.

But for some reason, I cannot change the case of the app name. It comes as "licecap.app" by default and I would really like to change its name to "LICEcap.app", but it just won't let me. I can change it to any other name, but whenever I try to name it "LICEcap", it just reverts right back to its all-lowercase "licecap".

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I've discovered something else which may or may not be helpful: If I go into the package contents of the app and change the instances of "licecap" in the info.plist file into "LICEcap", it lets me rename the app to whatever uppercase/lowercase I want, but corrupts the app (Finder says I should move it to the trash).

Comment: Can you change it to another name first, then change back with the case adjusted as you want it?

Comment: How are you trying to change the file name?  In Finder, or in the Terminal?

Comment: @Tyson I've tried that, but it just reverts it back to the lowercase version of the name.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the name because the filesystem is case independent. It is possible to change the filesystem to case dependent, but I would not recommend this. `LICEcap` and `licecap` are the same!

As others have pointed out in the comments the easiest way is to change to another name first.

Another way is to issue the following command in `Terminal`

```
mv licecap.app LICEcap.app
```

Comment: Changing it to another name then changing it to "LICEcap" preserves the letters, but it somehow reverts it to lowercase a short second after. The `mv` command didn't work either. (Although strangely, after renaming, `ls` shows "LICEcap.app" while Finder shows "licecap.app")